# Is there java.util.concurrent equivalent for WeakHashMap?

Tags: java, collections, guava, java.util.concurrent, weakhashmap

Can the following piece of code be rewritten w/o using `Collections.synchronizedMap()` yet maintaining correctness at concurrency?

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<Class, Object>());
```

i.e. is there something from java.util.concurrent one can use instead? Note that merely replacing with

```
new ConcurrentHashMap<Class, Object>(new WeakHashMap<Class, Object>()));
```

obviously won't work

Comment: The important benefit of highly concurrent data structures such as `ConcurrentHashMap` is that it can (through a variety of techniques) remain thread-safe under heavy load without (much) blocking.  It is important to realize that if your class is not under heavy load, your performance with ConcurrentHashMap could be *worse* than with HashMap.  If your environment is expected to be largely free of contention that you can use external synchronization and you'll be just fine.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [CacheBuilder](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) class allows you to do this easily.

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder().weakKeys().build()
```

Note that this changes key equality semantics to be `==` instead of `.equals()` which will not matter in your case of using `Class` instances but is a potential pitfall.

Comment: Updated link to Guava: https://github.com/google/guava
and updated link for CacheBuilder: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html

Answer (score 23):

I don't believe there is. In fact the javadoc suggests using Collections.synchronizedMap()

"Like most collection classes, this class is not synchronized. A synchronized WeakHashMap may be constructed using the Collections.synchronizedMap method."

Comment: @rogerdpack: but you could always compose a WeakHashMap into a roll-your-own `ThreadSafeWeakHashMap` and, using a monitor lock, write your own putIfAbsent(...) pretty easily.  Agreed that this would be suboptimal under heavy loads but not everything is heavily loaded.

Comment: @rogerdpack it does now, Java 8 ftw

Answer (score 2):

[Cafeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) is a popular competitor of Guava cache.

```
- keys automatically wrapped in weak references
- values automatically wrapped in weak or soft references
```

usage:

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()
 .weakKeys()
 .weakValues()
 .build(key -> createExpensiveGraph(key));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does wrapping the WeakHashMap in a synchronized map still work
>   correctly for what you want to do, since the garbage collector can
>   modify the weakreferences directly at anytime, bypassing the
>   synchronized map wrapper? I think WeakHashMap only truly works in a
>   single threaded model.

As mentioned above, the documentation for WeakHashMap at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html specifically says:

> "A synchronized WeakHashMap may be constructed using the
>   Collections.synchronizedMap method"

Which implies to me that this technique must work in tandem with the garbage collector's behavior (unless the documentation is buggy!)

Comment: Correct.  The JVM is always multi-threaded.  There are GC threads, finalizer threads, and others.  If WeakHashMap didn't work in an explicitly multithreaded Java program, it's hard to see how it could work in a single-threaded one either.

Comment: Huh? You are missing the whole question. He is asking for a weak version of ConcurrentHashMap (which uses a different algorithm than WeakHashMap).

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have the Spring Framework in your classpath already, then one option is `ConcurrentReferenceHashMap`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.html

You can choose between using [weak](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) or [soft](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) references (for both the keys and values).

Answer (score -1):

Does wrapping the WeakHashMap in a synchronized map still work correctly for what you want to do, since the garbage collector can modify the weakreferences directly at anytime, bypassing the synchronized map wrapper? I think WeakHashMap only truly works in a single threaded model.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Java 7 and above, this use case is solved in a thread-safe manner with  `ClassValue` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassValue.html  If you require the use of `remove`, think carefully about concurrency and read the doc thoroughly.

If you are using Java 6 or below.  No, you have to synchronize a WeakHashMap.